# Trajectory of Circumference [circle] Rolling Down any Given Curve

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, functions

How should I go about describing mathematically the path traced by the center of a circumference [circle] rolling down (or up) any given curve described by $y = f(x)$?

The solution for a linear function $f(x)$ is trivial which is equivalent to the well-known problems of rolling a circle on a flat or inclined line. In case there exists no such generalization, maybe I could calculate it's path rolling down some well known curve, such as a hyperbola, a $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$ (a parabola should not be so much of a trouble).

Comment: When you write “circunference”, do you mean “circle”? If I understand your question correctly, you are asking about a curve [parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve) to the original, except for those parts where a circle centered on that parallel curve would intersect the curve itself in some other point. [This alternative definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve#Alternative_definitions) appears to describe just that situation. There is literature on that topic, but for a more concrete answer I guess you should ask about a single class of input curves.

Answer (score 2):

Let $r$ be the radius of the rolling circle. The unit normal to the graph (pointing up) is   $(-f'(x),1)/\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}$. So, if the circle has radius $r$, its parametric equation *should be* 
$$(x,y) = (t,y(t)) + r(-f'(t),1)/\sqrt{1+f'(t)^2} \tag1$$ 
I emphasized *should*, because the point described by (1) may happen to be at distance less than $r$ from some other point on the graph. This means the circle gets stuck within a narrow bend of the graph. It is not easy to identify exactly where this happens, but if the curvature of the graph is less than $1/r$ at every point, then the circle does not get stuck and formula (1) is the answer.

Comment: I would say that the resulting curve crosses itself. Curves that do this are perfectly fine parametric curves and should not be discriminated against.

Comment: @martycohen I hope that such a curve won't take it personally, but I just don't see it as describing the center of a disk rolling on a graph, if it comes closer than $r$ to the graph.